# How to loop same code through all options in a drop-down list in Selenium WebDriver using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am new to both C# and Selenium WebDriver. I am trying to select value from dropdown, login to a application, and verify successfully logged in scenario and trying to repeat same piece of code for all options in dropdown.

How to get all values/options from a drop-down list and loop through those values?

I am getting below error Message on line

```
String timeTraveItemValue = timeTravelElementCount.ElementAt(i).Text;
```

> OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
>         (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)

HTML Code for the dropdown:

```
<div id="dvTimeTravel" class="pull-right">
    <select name="ctl00$ddlTimeTravel" id="ddlTimeTravel">
        <option value="1">Open</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="2">Pre</option>
        <option value="3">Post</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Selenium C# Code:

```
// Verify login scenario for all types of time travel- Open, Pre,Post
//Getting All the values from dropdown
SelectElement timeTravel = new SelectElement(Driver.WaitAndFindElement(By.Id("ddlTimeTravel"), 30));
IList<IWebElement> timeTravelElementCount = timeTravel.Options;
int ItemSizeTR = timeTravelElementCount.Count;
Console.WriteLine("ItemSizeTR = " + ItemSizeTR);
for (int i = 0; i < ItemSizeTR; i++)
{

    String timeTraveItemValue = timeTravelElementCount.ElementAt(i).Text;
    String FinalItemValuesTR = timeTraveItemValue.Trim();
    Console.WriteLine("FinalItemValuesTR = " + timeTraveItemValue);

    // Verify user is able to select time travel options, login into appliation, and verify logo based on time travel
    Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00$contentPlaceholder$txtUsername")).SendKeys("Username");
    Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00$contentPlaceholder$txtPassword")).SendKeys("password");
    Driver.FindElement(By.Id("contentPlaceholder_btnLogin")).Click();

    Assert.IsTrue(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("topLogo")).Displayed);
}
```

Comment: Notice that there's an attribute on one of the options: `selected`  By iterating through the options, you are dynamically changing that attribute, which makes the list of options become stale - the state has changed.  You need to re-read the list inside your loop.

Comment: Does your HTML page gets refreshed each time after selecting values from drop-down?

Comment: Yes, page gets refreshed each time after selecting values from drop-down @Magesh

Comment: Could you please explain me how to implement that @BillHileman

Comment: I don't program in C# so I would only be able to guess at the syntax, but simply add `timeTravelElementCount = timeTravel.Options;` to the beginning of your loop, I would think.  If that doesn't do it, you might also have to place `timeTravel = new SelectElement(Driver.WaitAndFindElement(By.Id("ddlTimeTravel"), 30));` before that line inside the loop as well.  Keep the original declarations so that the count can be established.